# How do I get SkyDrive synced storage to show up in my SkyDrive?

Tags: onedrive

When I access the Live Mesh program running on my computer, which syncs selected folders to other machines and/or SkyDrive, it lists the capacity of the `SkyDrive synced storage` option as 5 GB.

I have selected this option for a folder of PDF files. Clicking on the storage location takes me to a URL with a base of `http://devices.live.com/Devices/SkyDriveSyncedStorage`.

This is a different location than `skydrive.live.com`, which after I log into, shows none of the PDF's and a capacity of 25 GB

How can I have LiveMesh backup also go to SkyDrive? I am interested in this particularly because Microsoft recently released an iPhone app for SkyDrive that would allow me to access files from the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

When I go to `http://devices.live.com/Devices/SkyDriveSyncedStorage`, I see a listing of my synced folders. I have only synced one. Clicking on it takes me to `https://devices.live.com/Sync/FolderSelf`, which is a view of the folder's contents. Inside there is a PDF document. I click on it, and it opens.

I think the confusion is with the naming, the 5GB *SkyDrive Synced Storge* is actually a separate product than the 25GB *SkyDrive*. I guess *SkyDrive* is an unbrella name they're trying to brand all their consumer cloud apps under. It just confuses people. I don't know why they don't use the *Azure* name. *Azure Synced Storage*, *Azure SkyDrive*, and *Azure Cloud Services* would have made more sense -- to me at least.

Answer (score 1):

In short, because of how fragmented and unintegrated Microsoft's various sync and cloud services (not to mention how confusing the names are), this is not possible.

The (misnamed) SkyDrive storage associated with Live Mesh does not at all integrated with SkyDrive. Moving files between the two would be a manual process.

This is all explained at this [ArsTechnica article](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/reviews/2010/06/windows-live-sync-is-frustratingly-bad-it-could-be-awesome.ars).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a "backdoor" method im using:

1. First, share your SkyDrive/Google Drive folder on the local network, giving everyone "full control" (the SkyDrive/Google Drive folders are usually in `C:\Users\[YOUR USE NAME HERE]\`).
2. Next, use the advanced NTFS permissions to clear all other's rights (ESPECIALLY "EVERYONE"!). Then, add your Windows account(s) that you want access to it and give them the "full control" NTFS privilege.
3. Last, map a network drive to the share you designated as your skydrive synced folder.

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/34q90rs.png]

That’s all there is to it! It won't show up as a hard disk, but as a network drive. Nonetheless, it will still be in "My Computer". On the plus side, you can access it from any computer on your local network using your account's credentials! (Using NTFS permissions, you can tailor exactly who and what people can view/access, but it's a little time consuming.)

EDIT: there is another method that works better here, but many people report that it doesn’t work: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57347395-285/how-to-map-your-skydrive-folder-in-windows-7/